# What does x &&= y mean?

Tags: javascript

I found an assignment I don't understand. It mixes the logical AND operator `&&` with an `=`:

```
x &&= y
```

What does it mean?

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment/

Comment: @Bergi ty, I searched for a duplicate but couldn't find one. I moved my answer over there.

Comment: Added the dupe to [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript) in case you ever need to find it again. (I wasn't able to find a dupe myself either.)

Comment: @leonheess Thanks! I didn't realise this was meant to be a canonical question before I saw your edit to "*What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?*". The old one needs a bit cleanup, yours would be better phrased - but I don't think it matters enough to reverse the duplicate (or even merge them).

Comment: @Bergi Agreed, I hope someone will find my answer helpful over there